# DRF: How to insert data in another model class on deleting on model class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to insert data on one modal class on destroying another model class. My First model class:

```
class UserDevice(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(
        'Device',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    hardware_serial = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class NewDevice(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(
        'Device',
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
    )
    hardware_serial = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Whenever I will destroy the `UserDevice` I want to the same device should be added in `NewDevice`

My serializer class is :

```
class UserDeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserSensorDevice
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['id','created_at']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        app_id = models.UserDevice.objects.filter(sensor_code= validated_data.get('hardware_serial', None)).first()
        if app_id:
            msg = _('Application ID is already registered')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')
        else :
            return models.UserDevice.objects.create(**validated_data)

class NewDeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.NewDevice
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['id','created_at']
```

My view class:

```
class UserSensorRemoveDevice(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = models.UserDevice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserDeviceSerializer
```

What I have tried to override UserDevice destroy. But somehow its not working:

```
def destroy(self, validated_data):
        return models.NewDevice.objects.create(type = validated_data.get('type', None),hardware_serial = validated_data.get('hardware_serial', None))
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about override UserDevice.delete() method?

Comment: I have tried that but somehow it's not working. I have edited my code.Kindly check @weAreStarDust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `UserDevice.delete()` method

```
class UserDevice(models.Model):

    ...

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        NewDevice.objects.create(type=self.type, hardware_serial=self.hardware_serial)
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

in can just override your model UserDevice  delete function

```
def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
    #add new NewDevice instance
    super().delete(using, keep_parents,*args,**kwargs)
```